# show marker depends on address in database-Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a application in django in which i want to set a google map which should show the marker depends on address in database.

I want to know how to do this in javascript and django.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to read more about Google Maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

- Here is how you can convert address to coords: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
- Here is how to put simple marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

In Django, all you have to do is just get this address as a string from DB (in view) and pass it to template.

In javascript you are making variable:
`var address = "{{ address_from_view }}";` and everything else you do using only plain javascript & Google API.

Comment: I am saving the address field via models form,address contains 4 fields,i can query and get the value from database.But how to convert it to string.I need to convert the 4 field's data into a string.If i convert the address into string and render into template,is i need to save the data from database to json format,Thanks